# How do I validate that elements of a group (collection) are unique per parent object in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, validates-uniqueness-of

My app calls for `Courses` with `Projects` with `Groups` with `Users.` I need to make sure that `users` never appear more than once per `project` and I think I can do it with a Rails validation, but what I've got doesn't seem to want to work. Can anyone help me out with this?

The following gives me:

> **NoMethodError in Admin::GroupsController#create**
>   undefined method `text?' for nil:NilClass

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :project_id
  #has_and_belongs_to_many fields
  attr_accessible :user_ids

  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  belongs_to :project, :inverse_of => :groups

  validates :name, :project_id, :presence => true
  validates :user_ids, :uniqueness => { :scope => :project_id,
                                        :message => "Users can only be in one group per project." }
end
```

ActiveAdmin Group object:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Group do

  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :name
      f.input :users, :as => :check_boxes
      f.input :project
    end
    f.buttons
  end

end
```

Comment: can you put your groupscontroller too?

Comment: I'm actually using ActiveAdmin, uDaY, and that's what's giving me the error, but I'll post the contents.

Answer (score 1):

I would try

```
Course
  has_many :projects

Project
  has_many :groups
  has_many :users, :through => groups
  validates uniqueness_of :user

User
  has_many groups 
  has_many projects, :through => :groups

Group
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :group

# I stay away from has_and_belongs_to_many, not flexible later.
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems this validation occurs only when a Project is saved and I need validation to occur with operations on the Group.